# Iterate array then reset again multiple array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I want to iterate array then It should be reset again in PHP .
  The following logic  I want to implement

I have an array of smtp and a second array from which I just want to send 
 email once per smtp .
 Actually I have a list of array for which I want to send email but I have 
 few smtp hosts .
 I am iterating a list of array in foreach loop.
 I have a smtp array in which I have defined certain limit to send email.

```
function sendmail_test(){
   return "Sent<br/>";
}

$email_arrays=array(
   'test1@gmail.com',
   'test2@gmail.com',
   'test3@gmail.com',
   'test4@gmail.com',
   'test5@gmail.com',
   'test6@gmail.com',
);

$smtp_array=array(
   'gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com'=>10,
   'yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com'=>15
);


$smtp_count=count($smtp_array);
$smtp_counter=0;
for($i=0;$i<=$smtp_count;$i++){       

   foreach($email_arrays as $ek=>$ev){
        print_r($smtp_counter);
        echo sendmail_test();
    }
    $smtp_counter++;
}
```

Actually I want exactly like this.
I have currently have two smtp in **$smtp_array**

First email should be fired by like this smtp 
**`test1@gmail.com - >'gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com'`**

And second email should be fired by like this 
**`test2@gmail.com',->'yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com'`**

and then third email should be fired like this
**`test3@gmail.com - >'gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com'`**

which Is then reset and will use first smtp in **$smtp_array** ..
I hope you will get my point now.

Comment: your question is still unclear can you give us more details or where you are stuck now?

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you've posted?  You state what you want but not the problem you are having.

Comment: Also `$smtp_count` is 2 and in the loop you check `$i=0;$i<=$smtp_count` which will loop 3 times for 0, 1 and 2. Is that intended?

Comment: I have updated my answer .Please see it

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go though all the smtp servers and reset to the start when you had the last one, you might use [current](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php), [end](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php), [reset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php), and [next](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.next.php).

To get the value for the smtp, you could use [key](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) You can then [add an smtp server](https://3v4l.org/XDrPR) to the list as well.

For example:

```
function sendmail_test()
{
    return "Sent<br/>";
}

$email_arrays = array(
    'test1@gmail.com',
    'test2@gmail.com',
    'test3@gmail.com',
    'test4@gmail.com',
    'test5@gmail.com',
    'test6@gmail.com',
);

$smtp_array = array(
    'gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com' => 10,
    'yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com' => 15
);

$lastElement = end($smtp_array);
reset($smtp_array);

foreach ($email_arrays as $em) {
    $current = current($smtp_array);
    //sendmail_test();
    echo "Send email $em with smtp: " . key($smtp_array) . PHP_EOL;
    next($smtp_array);

    if ($lastElement === $current) {
        reset($smtp_array);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Send email test1@gmail.com with smtp: gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com
Send email test2@gmail.com with smtp: yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com
Send email test3@gmail.com with smtp: gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com
Send email test4@gmail.com with smtp: yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com
Send email test5@gmail.com with smtp: gmail_smtp@gmailsmtp.com
Send email test6@gmail.com with smtp: yogya_smtp@yogyasmtp.com
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/gB3EM)

Comment: Thank you so much The fourth bird.You just solved my problem. !!

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow So I can't accept this as correct..but you did a good job,

Comment: @NarendraSharma - You can mark the question as accepted (the grey "v" mark at the left of the answer) - it is nothing to do with the reputation you have

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this as following

```
$hosts = array_keys($smtp_array);
foreach($email_arrays as $k => $v){
  $email = $v;
  $host  = $hosts[$k%2];
  echo $email.'----'.$host;echo '<br/>';// use $email and $host to send the email
}
```

Comment: Thank you rakesh for commenting..I have updated my code. Please see my code again what I actually want